# the code below has failed to update db. thought it echos success

Tags: php

```
if (isset($_GET['edit'])) {
    global $conn;

    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, "UPDATE orders SET customerTelephone='delivered' WHERE orderId=? ");

    if (!$stmt){
        echo "Error preparing statement: " . mysqli_error($conn);
        exit;
    }
    
    if (!mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $_POST['edit'])){
        echo "Error binding parameters: " . mysqli_stmt_error($stmt);
        exit;
    }
    
    if (!mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)){
        echo "Error executing statement: " . mysqli_stmt_error($stmt);
        exit;
    } else {
        echo "Success! Order has been updated.";
    }

} else {
    echo "edit not set";
}
```

I have tried to check the query but found no issues, i need extra set of eyes on it. Help correct this code

Comment: First problem I see is that you first use `$_GET['edit']` in the if statement, and later `$_POST['edit']`

Comment: `$_GET['edit']` with `$_POST['edit']` ?

Comment: Also note that `mysql_stmt_execute()` will return `true` if the execution works fine. It is no guarantee that the database has been modified. If you for example call this with `id=123` and there is no such id in the database, it will still return true (there's no error in the SQL statement).